# "Tenant creation failed" when trying to create Azure B2C Tenant

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am currently unable to create an Azure B2C tenant. Error that I am getting is this "Tenant creation failed.". I am using a user with "Global Administrator" rights for creation. Also currently on a 'Free trial' license if it matters.

I have tried multiple regions to no avail. Audit Logs do not show any error reasons but instead states 'Success'. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What country did you select?

Comment: I tried United States, United Kingdon, Hong Kong to name a few

Answer (score 0):

I just successfully [created a b2c tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant) for testing, so make sure you meet the following conditions:

- You have the role of tenant administrator.
- Your account has been assigned a subscription.
- Switch to other countries or regions.
- In addition, Azure AD B2C team has started imposing limits on how many tenants can be created in subscription. Currently the limit is 20 B2C tenants per subscription. Can you try using a different subscription or deleting some tenants from the subscription to bring the number down below 20 to see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on March 3.  Same error.  The tenant actually does get created despite the error but something isn't completely set up because it doesn't appear in the list of tenants when you want to link a subscription to it.  I had tried different regions and also deleted all my existing b2c tenants.

It's probably just a server issue.  I waited a couple of days and the issue no longer occurs when I went to create another b2c tenant.